# Google login api error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am implementing google native login in my ionic app using [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) plugin. In google console I have a previous project `xyz` . I created a client ID using `web application` as application type (`Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs` fields left blank).

I am able to login and view user data.

Now I followed the same approach with another project using different google account. This time I am getting an error code `10` in response.

**P.S.** Google+ API is enabled in both cases.

Here is my code where I am putting my client id for reference

```
    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
{
  'scopes': 'email',
  'webClientId': 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  'offline': true,
},
function (obj) {
 alert(obj.email + "+++" + obj.displayName + "+++" + obj.userId); // do something useful instead of alerting
},
function (msg) {
  alert('error: ' + msg);
})
```

**P.S.** Google+ API is enabled in both cases.

Comment: what does error say ?

Comment: nothing its just an insane error code `10` in error callback

Answer (score 1):

Same problem is stated here [error code 10](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/248)

Make sure that your webClientId is correct

As described link above

> You need to pass in a Web Application type client ID to the login
>   function

Comment: ofcourse my webClientId is correct and link u mentioned above is redirecting to my own question

Answer (score 0):

check following things.

**1.** The problem occurs if you created `sha1` fingerprint with different  system and building your app in different system.
make sure you are building the app in the same system which you generated `sha1` fingerprint to add in google developer console.

**2.** you no need to add `webClientId` id but you have to use webClientId while installing the plugin.
like
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`